# Accessing Directive attribute value inside the Template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive that is included in the html as follow:

```
<w3-test-directive id="first" url="tableParams" sql="select *from     table1"></w3-test-directive>

<w3-test-directive id="second" url="tableParams2" sql="select *from     table2"></w3-test-directive>
```

Now in my directive Template i want the value of attribute id.
How can I get that?

My template is as follow:

```
template: [
                    '<p>The attribute value is {{value of id attribute}}<p>'
]
```

so the template would look some thing like this:

```
 "<p>The attribute value is first<p>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use template function which provides arguments element and attributes.

```
template : function(element, attrs){  
   return  '<p>ID is ' + element[0].id +'<p>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine, with a directive declaration like thus...

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        id: '@',
        url: '@',
        sql: '@'
    }
    // and the rest
}
```

...you would be able to access `id` directly since it's bound to your scope.

```
template: '<p>The attribute value is {{id}}</p>
```

Comment: don't think template should be array